# Force message on git stash

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm using `git stash` a lot. Most of the time I forget to set a message (`git stash save <message>`).

**How** is it possible to **force message** on the normal `git stash` command?

From the git stash help page:

> Calling git stash without any arguments is equivalent to git stash save. A stash is by default listed as "WIP on branchname …", but you can give a more descriptive message on the command line when you create one.

Comment: If you want to use sourcetree the comment is optional.

Comment: I don't want to use SourceTree as I like the command line.

Comment: All that `git stash` does is make a commit (well, really, *two* commits). The most-special thing about the stash commit is that it's not on any branch at all; but if you're making a lot of stashes, you probably should just go ahead and make the commits yourself, on those branches, since that will help you manage them. Remember that as long as you haven't published a commit, you can rebase or reset it away without consequence.

Answer (score 2):

No need to force anything, you can stash with your own message:
`git stash save "Your stash message"`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for this issue is to write a small script that does all the checks you need before running `git stash` and create a Git alias for it. And, of course, don't forget to use it instead of `git stash`.

The steps:

1. The script can be as simple as this:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   git stash save "${1:?You must provide a message.}"
   ```

   Save it as `~/bin/stash-force.sh`.
2. Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/bin/stash-force.sh
   ```
3. Create a Git alias that expands to this script:

   ```
   git config --global alias.stash-force '!~/bin/stash-force.sh'
   ```

   The exclamation mark in front of the script name tells Git the rest of the alias value is a script on its own. Git runs it using the original arguments of the `git stash-force` command.
4. Use it:

   ```
   git stash-force "message here"
   ```

   If you run it without arguments, the `${1:?}` parameter expansion kicks in and, because `$1` is not set, displays the error message.

Of course, now you must not forget to run `git stash-force` instead of `git stash` (or better find a shorter name for the alias). This is an annoyance as you have to remember to use `git stash-force` to create a stash and `git stash` for the other stash commands.

As an improvement, you can expand the script a little, check the values of `$#` (the number of arguments) and `$1` (its first argument) then either display an error and exit or call `git stash` for all sub-commands of `git stash`. This way you can use only the alias and ignore `git stash` completely.

However, you cannot replace `git stash` using an alias. It is specified in the [`git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-alias) that an alias that has the same name as an internal Git command is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a built-in way in Git to do that. If you don't want to define an alias or write a (differently named) helper script but stick to calling `git stash` you could

1. modify the shell script at `$(git --exec-path)/git-stash` to check the `stash_msg` variable in `save_stash ()` to be non-empty, or
2. rename `$(git --exec-path)/git-stash` to `$(git --exec-path)/git-stash-orig` and create a new `$(git --exec-path)/git-stash` that simply calls `$(git --exec-path)/git-stash-orig` except that is checks the command line for a given message in case of the `save` subcommand first.